# Can we create new abstract method in extended abstract class in java

Tags: java, abstract-class, extends

I am learning java from last month.
I am having a doubt regarding abstract classes.
I am trying to add another method which in abstract class **test**, but complirer is throwing an error.
Could you please tell what i had done wrong in this code ?

**Error -  cannot find symbol - method err()**

```
 class abstct 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        one obj = new error();
        obj.show();
        obj.test();
        obj.err();
    }
}
abstract class one
{
    abstract void show();
    abstract void test();
}
abstract class two extends one
{
    public void show()
    {
         System.out.println("Understood");
    }
    abstract void test();
}
abstract class three extends two
{
    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println("Understood");
    }
    abstract void err();
}
class error extends three
{
    public void err()
    {
       System.out.println("Here I am getting error .. ??");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you please please add error messages or whatever issue it is that you encounter?

Comment: Your first step should be learning [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Answer (score 3):

Please follow java standard and set uppercase the first letter of the class.

Here you instanciate an `Error` class but you put it in a `Inter` properties. it is valid as `Error` extends `Inter`. But it also mean that you can only use the method of the `Inter` properties. So you have access to `show` and `test`.

Here is the code you can use

```java
public class Abstr {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Inter obj = new Error();
        if (obj instanceof Test){
            ((Test)obj).err();
        }
        obj.show();
        obj.test();
    }
}

abstract class Inter {
    abstract void show();

    abstract void test();
}

abstract class Impl extends Inter {
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("Understood");
    }
}

abstract class Test extends Impl {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Understood");
    }

    abstract void err();
}

class Error extends Test {
    public void err() {
        System.out.println("Here I am getting error .. ??");
    }
}
```

note in jdk14, there is a preview of pattern matching, and if enable you could write:

```java
if (obj instanceof Test){
   obj.err();
}
```

Comment: ((Error )obj).err(); is also work